# Как создать 72х битную константу в assembler RISC-V?

Tags: ассемблер

Задача: необходимо вычислить формулу вида d = (a - b) + l - (-c) на языке assembler risk-v.
Проблема: все числа должны быть 9ти байтными, целыми, без знака.
Для разработки я использую эмулятор процессора с 32х битной архитектурой "RARS 1.5".
Я написал код, который решает аналогичную задачу для 16 битных чисел, но не могу понять, как реализовать 72х битные константы.
Кто сталкивался с подобной задачей, просьба написать, как у вас получилось решить данную проблему.

```
# d = (a - b) + l + c 
# s2 = a, s3 = b, s4 = c, s5 = l

.globl main # делает метку main глобальной

.data # сегмент глобальных данных
   A: .half 15 
   B: .half 10 
   C: .half 10 
   L: .half 10
   D: .space 4

.text     # сегмент кода
main:

# Определяем значения сохраняемых переменных
lh s2, A 
lh s3, B
lh s4, C 
lh s5, L
    
# Вычисляем формулу
sub t0, s2, s3 # a - b 
add t1, t0, s5 # (a - b) + l
sub s4, x0, s4 # -c 
add t2, t1, s4 # d = (a - b) + l -(-c)
sh  t2, D, x0 # сохраняем D в стек


# Вывод на консоль
li  a7, 1          # service 1 is print integer
    add a0, t2, zero   # загрузить желаемое значение (s0) в регистр аргументов a0
    ecall              # обращение к ОС
```